# Debug symbols not loaded when converting to .net 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have a .net 3.5 project in C# that hits breakpoints fine when I F5 it in Visual Studio 2010.  However, when I change the project target framework to .Net4, and hit F5, then the breakpoints are not hit.  If I mouse over the breakpoint icon i see that no debug symbols have been loaded for this document.  If I change the target framework back to .Net3.5, breakpoints are hit as expected.  Any pointers as to where I should look for why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Click Debug, Windows, Modules, right-click your assembly, and click Symbol Load Info.

Comment: Ah, now that you've added Windows to your answer it makes sense. Thanks.  However, my Modules window does not list my assembly.  It lists a whole lot of assemblies, but no my assembly.  Any idea why?  Interestingly, this is the case whether I set my project to target .Net 3.5 as well as .Net 4.0.